# Why does svg file not show correct font when glyphs are included?

Tags: html, css, svg, fonts, font-face

I have an svg file that is not showing the font correctly.  I am trying to display two characters.  I have the glyphs included in the font description.  The font descriptions are below.

```
<font horiz-adv-x="1000">
<!-- Copyright (C) Avid Technology, Inc. 1987-2010 -->
<!-- Copyright: Copyright 2014 Adobe System Incorporated. All rights reserved. -->
<font-face font-family="OpusText" units-per-em="1000" underline-position="-123" underline-thickness="20"/>
<missing-glyph horiz-adv-x="500"/>
<glyph unicode="#" horiz-adv-x="360" d="M239,371l-105,-35l0,-189l105,35M266,634l0,-156l56,19l0,-100l-56,-18l0,-189l56,18l0,-99l-56,-19l0,-170l-27,0l0,162l-105,-34l0,-163l-27,0l0,155l-57,-19l0,100l57,18l0,189l-57,-18l0,99l57,19l0,171l27,0l0,-163l105,34l0,164z"/>
<glyph unicode="b" horiz-adv-x="321" d="M50,635l35,0l-8,-316C100,356 134,375 179,375C194,375 209,372 224,367C239,361 252,353 263,343C274,333 283,321 290,308C297,294 300,279 300,263C300,240 293,218 279,196C264,173 245,151 222,129C199,106 172,84 142,61C112,38 81,14 50,-10M151,330C136,330 123,327 114,320C104,313 96,304 91,293C85,282 81,269 79,256C76,242 75,228 75,215l0,-47C75,111 77,73 81,54C95,64 110,78 126,96C141,114 155,133 168,154C181,174 191,194 200,215C208,235 212,253 212,268C212,285 206,299 195,312C183,324 168,330 151,330z"/>
```

The text call is as follows.

```
       <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 25 40)"><tspan   font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">#</tspan><tspan  font-family="'OpusText'" font-size="25">b</tspan></text>
```

The text is supposed to look like the following paths.  They are the shape of the glyphs.

```
<g transform="translate(0,50)">
     <path d="M39.137,24.426v3.9l1.4-0.475v2.5l-1.4,0.45v4.726l1.4-0.45v2.476l-1.4,0.475v4.25h-0.675v-4.05l-2.625,0.85v4.075h-0.675
    v-3.875l-1.425,0.475v-2.5l1.425-0.449v-4.726l-1.425,0.451v-2.476l1.425-0.475v-4.275h0.675v4.075l2.625-0.85v-4.1H39.137z
     M38.462,31.001l-2.625,0.875v4.726l2.625-0.875V31.001z"/>
     <path d="M42.736,24.401h0.875l-0.2,7.9c0.583-0.933,1.434-1.4,2.55-1.4c0.383,0,0.758,0.071,1.125,0.212
    c0.366,0.142,0.691,0.337,0.975,0.587c0.283,0.25,0.508,0.546,0.675,0.888c0.166,0.342,0.25,0.712,0.25,1.112
    c0,0.567-0.18,1.13-0.537,1.688c-0.359,0.559-0.83,1.117-1.413,1.675c-0.583,0.559-1.25,1.125-2,1.7s-1.517,1.163-2.3,1.763V24.401
    z M45.261,32.026c-0.383,0-0.696,0.087-0.938,0.263c-0.242,0.175-0.434,0.4-0.575,0.675c-0.142,0.274-0.242,0.584-0.3,0.925
c-0.059,0.342-0.087,0.68-0.087,1.013v1.175c0,1.434,0.05,2.384,0.15,2.851c0.35-0.25,0.721-0.601,1.113-1.051
c0.391-0.449,0.746-0.929,1.063-1.438c0.316-0.508,0.579-1.016,0.787-1.524s0.313-0.954,0.313-1.338
    c0-0.416-0.146-0.779-0.438-1.088C46.057,32.18,45.694,32.026,45.261,32.026z"/></g>
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing the fontface is not being shown, but rather some random unknown font.
http://jsfiddle.net/AU3MH/7/

Any ideas on why the font face is not being displayed?
I'm running windows 7 and internet explorer version 11.
Thanks,
--christopher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 11 [does not support SVG Fonts](http://caniuse.com/svg-fonts) so what you're seeing is just the ordinary TrueType glyphs.

Comment: If I define a font in my css and link to the font, then the svg font-face will work?
Something like this 
`@font-face{
    font-family: opusText;
    src: url(opustext.ttf);
}`

Comment: Sure, that's a truetype font, not an SVG font though.

Comment: It is weird.  When I define the font face and family in the css, then all the places where the text is defined with the same font face in every svg then display the font correctly.